# "Evaluation error: object '.' not found." when applying function to models in a list column

Tags: r, dplyr

I ran glm models for multiple groups with the dplyr "do" function. Now I want to apply the PseudoR2() function from the DescTool package to every model in the resulting list column. However, I get "Evaluation error: object '.' not found." apparently because the PseudoR2() wants to use the data used to generate the models, but the models have data = ., which does not exist in the environment.

The general question is, how to apply functions that need to access the original data to models that are generated using '.'?

Below is a reproducible example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(DescTools)

dta = tibble(id = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
             y = rnorm(8),
             x = rnorm(8))

dta %>% group_by(id) %>%
  do(fit = glm(y ~ x, data = .)) %>% 
  mutate(R2 = PseudoR2(fit))
```

Comment: Try `dta %>% group_by(id) %>% nest %>% mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% mutate(R2 = glm(y ~ x) %>% PseudoR2))) %>% unnest`

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to build the model after `nest`ing

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)
dta %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   nest %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, ~ 
       .x %>% 
       mutate(fit = list(glm(y ~ x)), R2 = map(fit, PseudoR2)))) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  unnest(R2)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  id         y      x fit              R2
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <list>        <dbl>
#1 A     -1.28   0.537 <S3: glm> 0.0000992
#2 A     -0.576 -0.508 <S3: glm> 0.0000992
#3 A     -0.635 -1.28  <S3: glm> 0.0000992
#4 A      0.324  0.272 <S3: glm> 0.0000992
#5 B     -0.329  0.290 <S3: glm> 0.0878   
#6 B     -1.13   0.432 <S3: glm> 0.0878   
#7 B     -1.42  -0.924 <S3: glm> 0.0878   
#8 B      0.551 -1.47  <S3: glm> 0.0878
```

Comment: This works, but seems very cumbersome for a simple operation. Could we come up with a solution that would be simpler than a for loop?

Comment: @DocHoliday  If you don't want to store the model as a column, then it can be further simplified

Answer (score 0):

This provides the desired outcome by calculating the McFadden's R2 directly, but does not solve the issue of applying functions when "data = .". Note that the problem in the PseudoR2() is the update() base function that wants to refit the model.

```
require(dplyr)
require(DescTools)

dta = tibble(id = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
             y = rnorm(8),
             x = rnorm(8))

dta %>% group_by(id) %>%
  do(fit = glm(y ~ x, data = .),
     fitNULL = glm(y ~ x, data = .)) %>% 
  mutate(PseudoR2 = 1 - logLik(fit)/logLik(fitNULL))
```